# Finding values (array) within a cellarray in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to find a more efficient way of finding the index of an array within a cellarray other than using 'for' loops. My problem is as follows:

```
a = [6,3]
b = {[1,10];[1,8,10];[8,10];[2,8];2;[2,4,5];[2,4];[];[3,6];[3,4,6];6;[3,5,6];[6,9];[1,6,9];[1,6,7,9]}
```

I need to find the index of 'a' within 'b'. My current method works but is quite slow and cumbersome when you increase the size of 'b' which is my case. I'm not interested in the order of the array, only that the contents are the same which is why I use the 'setxor' method. The code below shows an example of how I currently do this.

```
for num = 1:size(b,1)       
    new_array(num,1) = isempty(setxor(a, b{num,1}));
    if (new_array(num,1) == 1)
       indexOfArray = num; 
       break; 
    end;
end;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Comment: What do you mean with 'contents are the same'? Is `[1 1 1 1 2]` the same as `[2 1]` ? Otherwise you may need to sort them first and then check for full equality.

Comment: No, those two arrays have the same values but not the same contents. I mean in the sense where [1 2 3], [1,3,2], [3,2,1] etc... all have identical contents though not in the same order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
find(cellfun(@(x) isempty(setxor(a,x)), b))
```

If you only want the first coincidence, use

```
find(cellfun(@(x) isempty(setxor(a,x)), b), 1)
```

This uses your definition of coincidence, in terms of `setxor`.

Thanks to @Dan and @DennisJaheruddin for their constructive comments, which have been incorporated into this answer.

Comment: Probably stick with `isempty(setxor(a,x))` over `isequal`

Comment: @Dan Well, I've tested a bit and `isequal` seems to be faster

Comment: The 'first' addition is not required as it is the default setting.

Comment: @LuisMendo you could do `sort(a)` and still have decent performance. But that might not be a general solution. It looks like it is though based on the example data

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the help. Knew there was a better way of doing it but just couldn't quite get it. Cheers.

Comment: Just made the changes to my code and it appears that my original solution works faster than the 'cellfun' method. Maybe due to the fact that I break the search loop upon finding a match thus cut short the search time in a number of cases.

Comment: Yes, `cellfun` sometimes turns out to be slow; and in this case there's also the aspect of exiting the loop early as you say

Comment: You said you want to match `a` and `b` without regard to order. However, if each vector in `b` is ordered, as in your example, you can sort `a` at the beginning (`a = sort(a)`) and then use `isequal(a,x)` instead of `isempty(setxor(a,x))`. That will save time

Comment: That will work different if the vectors contain repeated elements though, as @DennisJaheruddin pointed out

Comment: @Luis: Just tried your method and it is a little faster. In my problem, 'b' is is always presorted in the format you see in the example due to the way in which it is created so Thank you for this!